# android native crashed,the phone record the google-breakpad report,but how to read it and find the reason?

Tags: android, webview, gatt, google-breakpad

```
07-07 05:37:54.712 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
```

07-07 05:37:54.713 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: V AndroidWebView:57.0.2987.132
07-07 05:37:54.713 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: O A arm64 04 aarch64 Xiaomi/gemini/gemini:7.0/NRD90M/7.5.4:user/release-keys
07-07 05:37:54.713 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: P browser
07-07 05:37:54.713 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: G OpenGL ES 3.2 V@145.0 (GIT@Ie4d56a70f3)|Qualcomm|Adreno (TM) 530
07-07 05:37:54.713 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0 0000007F847C6FD0 0000007F847C6000 0000000000001000
07-07 05:37:54.713 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6000 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.713 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6180 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.714 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6300 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.714 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6480 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.714 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6600 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.715 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6780 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.715 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6900 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.715 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6A80 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.715 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6C00 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.715 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6D80 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.715 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: S 0000007F847C6F00 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
07-07 05:37:54.716 24137 32072 F google-breakpad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
07-07 05:37:54.716 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000005555555000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 0A7071C7CFEB04622EC4016CE5F39ACD0 app_process64
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 000000007080F000 00000000005A2000 0000000000409000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 00000000710BA000 00000000004A0000 0000000000316000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-core-libart.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000071443000 0000000000071000 0000000000058000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-conscrypt.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000071528000 000000000008B000 0000000000065000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-okhttp.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000071599000 000000000000A000 0000000000003000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-core-junit.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 000000007170A000 000000000016C000 0000000000047000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-bouncycastle.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000071871000 000000000011E000 0000000000043000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-ext.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 00000000731D8000 0000000001922000 00000000010EC000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-framework.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 00000000745DB000 0000000000315000 0000000000221000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-telephony-common.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 000000007482F000 0000000000031000 0000000000012000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-voip-common.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 000000007486E000 000000000002B000 000000000001C000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-ims-common.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 00000000749DC000 0000000000150000 0000000000025000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-apache-xml.oat
07-07 05:37:54.717 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074AB3000 00000000000B0000 0000000000076000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-org.apache.http.legacy.boot.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074B2E000 0000000000003000 0000000000001000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-tcmiface.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074B37000 0000000000006000 0000000000001000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-telephony-ext.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074B4F000 0000000000015000 0000000000002000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-WfdCommon.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074B56000 0000000000003000 0000000000001000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-oem-services.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074B72000 0000000000019000 0000000000004000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-qcom.fmradio.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074B80000 0000000000008000 0000000000001000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-qcmediaplayer.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074D0B000 0000000000188000 0000000000034000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-miui.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000000074E30000 00000000000EF000 0000000000018000 000000000000000000000000000000000 boot-miuisystem.oat
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F59D73000 0000000000000000 0000000000109000 52AF51F9D1FA7DAA561D021AB1C80CAB0 libblas.so
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7E156000 00000000002BD000 0000000000270000 000000000000000000000000000000000 WebViewGoogle.odex
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7EE90000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 B933D3445554C18D3D0F3115FABE7F910 libunwind.so
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7EF16000 0000000000000000 0000000000020000 A667DE9A1B9342A0792D87ECDC0797360 libutils.so
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7EF39000 0000000000000000 000000000000F000 43464F532EA6BF6A58D978FD4B89F7F30 libbacktrace.so
07-07 05:37:54.718 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7EF4B000 0000000000000000 000000000000B000 32A74BDBF89F698D7D686F948166F1D40 libbase.so
07-07 05:37:54.719 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7EF4F000 0000000000000000 00000000000E1000 56BE84F5391B03807C422A7EB9D3B3AC0 libc++.so
07-07 05:37:54.719 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7F03C000 0000000000000000 000000000019C000 85AAE0FD2EA1DF47E53124262555CD1E0 libhyphenate.so
07-07 05:37:54.719 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7F209000 0000000000000000 0000000000025000 AFB06673527124FD46E557D9628A73A60 liblzma.so
07-07 05:37:54.719 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7F234000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 6175FF2427FC1EEDFDA84CDB775E012B0 libcutils.so
07-07 05:37:54.719 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7F250000 0000000000000000 00000000000FB000 0D0D64DAAC71FD11EBE6E71CF006204C0 libsqlite.so
07-07 05:37:54.720 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7F35B000 0000000000000000 0000000000813000 A1B425F02B77DFE5B1DB969A4921D5340 libhyphenate_av.so
07-07 05:37:54.720 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F8170B000 0000000000000000 00000000000BD000 1CEEDB3555807DDA367F25E43A95A04D0 libRSCpuRef.so
07-07 05:37:54.720 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F81B3F000 0000000000000000 0000000000033000 A10C7BBAD6051DD0F6B95DEFD7507A400 libRSDriver.so
07-07 05:37:54.720 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F83AAA000 0000000000000000 000000000000C000 25745D77F1A2FA7CAE5E9AF26BE6A68F0 eglSubDriverAndroid.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F8533F000 000000000086A000 000000000000A000 000000000000000000000000000000000 base.odex
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F87355000 0000000000000000 0000000002000000 000000000000000000000000000000000 dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F8A355000 0000000000B72000 0000000003979000 1837DCE352E3B78F00C87296FEA41A990 libwebviewchromium.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F91CB9000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 EB9549FD3C0235FD4CB9123FE538DB590 libwebviewchromium_loader.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F91DD0000 0000000000000000 0000000000020000 0C9EC5FB246E32DE3B9BBBB85304EDBC0 libcompiler_rt.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F91E5E000 0000000000000000 0000000000007000 F80D675E9F262326FEE4A24ED7321A560 libmemalloc.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F91E67000 0000000000000000 0000000000006000 6302517A1E98B73A5E101C744469913B0 gralloc.msm8996.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F91E69000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 3F40A6680F0A92FDBBAA9BBE2313E9510 libqservice.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F91E83000 0000000000000000 0000000000005000 2B501C6E2B1643F2F1B693F446092B650 libqdutils.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F91E8A000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 E2FCEF838A7D9BBE81994E43C43042C80 libqdMetaData.so
07-07 05:37:54.721 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F91E33000 0000000000000000 0000000000D8E000 3C176ACAD2486113657CAC560528A8790 libllvm-glnext.so
07-07 05:37:54.725 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F92BE2000 0000000000000000 00000000004C5000 43A8669D541255191676245C4EC45C020 libGLESv2_adreno.so
07-07 05:37:54.727 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F93343000 0000000000000000 000000000003A000 BDF15625689616C81B68AC72004A58540 libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
07-07 05:37:54.728 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9337E000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 E0F344C9C89075AF0CAD4940643894730 libEGL_adreno.so
07-07 05:37:54.728 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F93395000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 05BB3CA989D0F504DCF65A643BB9F2F60 libmiuinative.so
07-07 05:37:54.729 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F938AD000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 36D97CBCF1B6E85B140E366626967F630 libkeystore-engine.so
07-07 05:37:54.729 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F938B1000 0000000000000000 0000000000020000 51B252DD45300621A0DE088306E557780 libsoftkeymasterdevice.so
07-07 05:37:54.729 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F938D1000 0000000000000000 000000000001E000 31499958466F177883B5EF5F85197E860 libkeystore_binder.so
07-07 05:37:54.729 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F938F4000 0000000000000000 000000000000F000 8191D2F9E326422B2FEAA427AA5177E60 libkeymaster_messages.so
07-07 05:37:54.729 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F93903000 0000000000000000 0000000000029000 0AA0D148632972AC6883691F96A749D50 libjavacrypto.so
07-07 05:37:54.729 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9392E000 0000000000000000 000000000002E000 2AD9C6A1DED5952ADC2EF24BBB349F520 libkeymaster1.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F93960000 0000000000000000 0000000000007000 7DC8A64564A2358F7A7FECBC198E01460 libadreno_utils.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F939BC000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 0B5CFCF41AF3470EB31F8032F8E6B9750 libmtp.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F939E0000 0000000000000000 0000000000010000 0AFC3DE4530669A5F382751127DD93700 libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F939E8000 0000000000000000 000000000002F000 FBE04B938B9EB4C2E372D70B304A983D0 libexif.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F93A22000 0000000000000000 000000000007C000 D8D5C0C10E38C36FECF13F9B227FB3100 libmedia_jni.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F93AC3000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 957A01FA3E7B2A8948015CD6EEFE6A990 libextmedia_jni.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F980B6000 0000000000000000 0000000000144000 01BD26E755EF42AED908568986CF751D0 libxml2.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9861E000 0000000000000000 000000000000D000 000000000000000000000000000000000 libshella-2.10.4.1.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F99E80000 0000000000000000 00000000003EC000 D8C44B9DF3014A6660F498526017376F0 libart-compiler.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A284000 0000000000000000 00000000000D4000 3CAC601505EC32062CF777C43CE88EB50 libvixl.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A385000 0000000000000000 000000000003F000 CBC6D52B77FE8C3918B4895C9653DC380 libopenjdk.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A3C4000 0000000000000000 000000000003D000 405C54B5E68A397AF200A48F4165F3D20 libjavacore.so
07-07 05:37:54.730 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A406000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 39AE81637AEDB01959D4A9E892BABDE90 libtime_genoff.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A40A000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 870C97FC860566D6EB0E18D344B45B620 libqmi_client_helper.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A40F000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 DFB328A7A4FE785F9E68B98804586CCF0 libdsutils.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A427000 0000000000000000 000000000000B000 4CFEF8D1ADAA509D9E40A841FE2979D70 libqmi_cci.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A432000 0000000000000000 000000000001E000 A2142F3332A882D3CFFA5C62DDB024C20 libnetmgr.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A453000 0000000000000000 000000000002B000 FE109811C88EB707A0F11BFE0175F1190 lib-imsrcscm.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A481000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 A15924805D6DD3D7FCB8F1BDCD1A57C80 libqmi_encdec.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A487000 0000000000000000 0000000000007000 1DD1061ED229AF48350CC1401A7061E00 libxml.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A48B000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 82921F6B63255DA615C6BE1F614274A30 libqdi.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A4AC000 0000000000000000 0000000000192000 6944C2F5C39A6464C3624F113B5BDAC00 lib-imsqimf.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A644000 0000000000000000 000000000003B000 1D5893BE9807841E37F901ED8AE3871F0 libqmi.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A7EC000 0000000000000000 0000000000009000 20503B099D5681853CAC2A7D71EF003B0 libqmi_client_qmux.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A828000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 AAA8C7D8281CFE51C94083D1A2A1F2E50 libdiag.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9A938000 0000000000000000 00000000000C5000 506F39919ADDA39AC18E046A7C6234B90 lib-imsxml.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9AA0D000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 4FC73A8D29EA0C753DAF91EA910100C30 libidl.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9AA04000 0000000000000000 0000000000021000 DF664CBEE95B84FA54812F5957278EF90 libqmiservices.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9AA33000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 D61AE25BD1F70F056E144A9A5F70B0C90 libconfigdb.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9AA3A000 0000000000000000 000000000007C000 2BA353C60DE344E871BEE706E2D74E340 lib-imsdpl.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9AAAB000 0000000000000000 000000000007E000 E4450EAA45C0D6905557BAB50C59D24C0 libdsi_netctrl.so
07-07 05:37:54.731 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9AB44000 0000000000000000 0000000000017000 A270BCFC66DA61ED8FBC671DE6DFA04B0 lib-imsrcscmservice.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9AB54000 0000000000000000 000000000010A000 CA499244A2094D83F78E11320B25D3E20 libCB.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9EF0E000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 6E8ED87B5820597E0176ED8B86BE49520 libBugly.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F1E4000 0000000000004000 0000000000002000 000000000000000000000000000000000 QPerformance.odex
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FFE0000 0000000000000000 000000000060A000 1540B2139D1D613272038F90872C81710 libart.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0A02000 0000000000000000 0000000000059000 563A7F4F81B725751BBCCC97069718230 libgsl.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0B9F000 0000000000000000 0000000000025000 AFB06673527124FD46E557D9628A73A60 liblzma.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0BCB000 0000000000000000 0000000000058000 09C922AD365B4ACF4D72CA7EA40F06A70 libsonivox.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0C2D000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 8CB8423E077F7D1AFB3F62E33C8FEFE00 libstagefright_yuv.so

Answer (score 0):

continue for the google-breakpad:

07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0C32000 0000000000000000 0000000000005000 63F61AC2366F896C6169B2D75E0CE0180 libpowermanager.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0B97000 0000000000000000 0000000001198000 C7261F57350C3D873C0DA4E3A037055C0 libLLVM.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1DF6000 0000000000000000 000000000000A000 EF46D0E809ECA9C45AE64D478B2396B60 libnbaio.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1E03000 0000000000000000 0000000000008000 361B8B83C4C2F86891699D65BF1C20E70 libhardware_legacy.so
07-07 05:37:54.732 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1E0E000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 D837D25CAA62FCA75A07779645CA08950 libnetd_client.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1E12000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 9C07D582868EF369B3F6D498F15B92990 libstdc++.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1E16000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 0F2E0AE99098E9EC742A8B28BBF545830 libimg_utils.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1DE6000 0000000000000000 00000000001D6000 06AA4B5EFF432EDFA1CFE97AC5D5ACBE0 libstagefright.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1FE3000 0000000000000000 0000000000016000 000DAB12B2E721C3A33BA596FEE8E2280 libsoundtrigger.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1FF8000 0000000000000000 000000000002C000 284CA18626F9A9A817542577419C2CD90 libinput.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA202D000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 B3BEDB325ABCECBB72039F1F0143806B0 libbinary_parse.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2031000 0000000000000000 0000000000049000 9D0C822C87B1D150165C3235392063A30 libRS_internal.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA207F000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 BD1EF65E210F87894B8BD684BF7DA0F30 libmemtrack.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2083000 0000000000000000 0000000000009000 FDDB04BE56260BFE15D2120DC59EF3120 libGLESv1_CM.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2041000 0000000000000000 000000000059A000 984D64A860D7FCE49FDBCB139416D6160 libskia.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA261F000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 8D7075A1EE2FBC7317EAF1B5EB6BF1520 libpackagelistparser.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2623000 0000000000000000 0000000000008000 C2EF72A3B820C94B6F9305F4F086B2BE0 libimage_type_recognition.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA262D000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 1162EE6DAB134C05F84AED6259FA65B60 libstagefright_enc_common.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2630000 0000000000000000 00000000000BB000 CD39E6BF7A54EF9EC0C1191EF7C87BAE0 libc.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA26FD000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 8F5553E70216C2C824C1349E055CEA340 libeffects.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA26E7000 0000000000000000 00000000004D8000 1A2733D26703793379041D0A9CCEEFBB0 libpdfium.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2B76000 0000000000000000 0000000000152000 4750B858C4AE94799163D8664061CD2D0 libmedia.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2D06000 0000000000000000 0000000000005000 72D7EE1152052D1FA0B155C826DD35FD0 libtiff_directory.so
07-07 05:37:54.733 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2D0D000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 4544DA167067A06329D6494F3BA397130 libnativebridge.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2CEE000 0000000000000000 0000000000095000 D5E3BF02B7E8C040FFEE568A75262F320 libgui.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2D9A000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 747CBC9ABA7E4597E68B8452EE5BB9320 libvulkan.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2DBA000 0000000000000000 000000000000A000 88A9B6EC3EB6EEB5EC346AE541FF2BB10 libpiex.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2DC6000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 8D7BAADF32B4CDFDD0A43C4A06CC18F00 libusbhost.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2DC2000 0000000000000000 0000000000046000 0F0DF6FD7296A0F8D9832C736A1AA0640 libwilhelm.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2E11000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 7686268422C270D3A819B03D9A3BF6AC0 libGLESv2.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2E28000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 8C8D63004EF713FC5AE44CD87BDAED840 libvorbisidec.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2E47000 0000000000000000 0000000000008000 5070F00A636AA255B6355B0BD8BDCFAE0 libaudioutils.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2E4A000 0000000000000000 0000000000016000 68B3EB8E6C3616AAE71046C3CA13FDC20 libradio.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2E67000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 4A5A80025B29EA6AC7EC2402254AA16D0 libz.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2E7E000 0000000000000000 0000000000038000 F44DF572278F5721F66DF2DCC50F9D860 libssl.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2EBA000 0000000000000000 000000000001B000 C9A6CB74B1FD23D0DDA9FAC1E383D09E0 libpcre.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2ECF000 0000000000000000 0000000000024000 D643064FF41DF326E013F625DB1720A40 libEGL.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2EFF000 0000000000000000 0000000000052000 0BD5A57C39CF5D59857721ECB517C4EB0 libharfbuzz_ng.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2F51000 0000000000000000 0000000000059000 BEBBA1D1187ABE8D2421C3E847B0811D0 libinputflinger.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2FB0000 0000000000000000 000000000004B000 22DD9304EE4D6F204DD9DB6DB54A472C0 libopus.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2FFE000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 A6007C9CE2CB8539CA6C370C088924420 libwpa_client.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2FEB000 0000000000000000 000000000005D000 4FC8254CC5E375D1CABCDC31C9FCA0660 libcamera_client.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA305A000 0000000000000000 0000000000033000 DF80EF068F712A9247496A86AE6128920 libpng.so
07-07 05:37:54.734 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA308F000 0000000000000000 0000000000022000 B00191BB36E8A07451577CB88028D80A0 libmemunreachable.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA30B3000 0000000000000000 0000000000042000 C44446630C4C5656C1E2244815D926CE0 libandroidfw.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA30F8000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 E3AD0ECD52595D65373DF95C6CF04F290 libprocessgroup.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA30FC000 0000000000000000 000000000000F000 43464F532EA6BF6A58D978FD4B89F7F30 libbacktrace.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA310E000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 0DCDE3B150A4AE4A9C64FC8EF44B44D80 libminikin.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA312E000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 9A3B6F644F6652D4944071DE7CD953680 libETC1.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA312A000 0000000000000000 00000000000E1000 56BE84F5391B03807C422A7EB9D3B3AC0 libc++.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA320F000 0000000000000000 0000000000028000 AC60831D7A2C052C479883DEC172A1B70 libdrmframework.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA323F000 0000000000000000 0000000000104000 0D3AE6A6E7B99D612AD33C4F028D5C6C0 libcrypto.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3358000 0000000000000000 0000000000022000 59E1F5B3BA40C7567CAF3E5CDB47B8950 libprotobuf-cpp-lite.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA337D000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 EC2B9432F963374AB2F749098DBD08DF0 libselinux.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3396000 0000000000000000 000000000000B000 F9BD65BF90FC2C810648C1D0F4FF2A4A0 libRS.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA338B000 0000000000000000 0000000000081000 8E5FEBFBEDD6ABC22E6DB667CA6C419E0 libbinder.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA341F000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 E388025DE110BEF00DE83E4174B317C90 libhardware.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3423000 0000000000000000 0000000000008000 586DC646669D51766B327453B0982A080 libstagefright_avc_common.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA342B000 0000000000000000 0000000000009000 B13DD8460CDC258BA0D162E1F9515F4E0 libcamera_metadata.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3437000 0000000000000000 0000000000007000 78910DA8720C99F7788C339514C79D9D0 libnativehelper.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3441000 0000000000000000 0000000000006000 5D5C40BC70839BCFF7F319F7F52FF4AF0 libnetutils.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3449000 0000000000000000 0000000000039000 D9DC2FD8FF0380F6BF304A655176CA000 libjpeg.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3483000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 6175FF2427FC1EEDFDA84CDB775E012B0 libcutils.so
07-07 05:37:54.735 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA34A3000 0000000000000000 0000000000009000 32B148D93B13807C65A5A3483C296B8A0 libnativeloader.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA34AE000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 BFF9D0E70FDC319189EA1F8A2B176FAE0 libradio_metadata.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA34B2000 0000000000000000 0000000000020000 A667DE9A1B9342A0792D87ECDC0797360 libutils.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA34D5000 0000000000000000 0000000000024000 C92ADED614992FE2BD74905DB4F3E9D40 libexpat.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA34FD000 0000000000000000 000000000004C000 D8793175B4B9B19D07D79C9B8FD99CD10 libbcinfo.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA354A000 0000000000000000 0000000000070000 DBDCBDCA95F0E4EB882B524C35B89EA60 libft2.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA35BF000 0000000000000000 0000000000010000 9A2752C688A6413FBD4882F2EDE52A810 libui.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA35A2000 0000000000000000 00000000001A8000 D487FC73FE77B249606198CF3949E1EC0 libandroid_runtime.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3769000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 81D3A32BFDEFF6593C170DA3B2982DAD0 libsync.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA376C000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 3006CE964E54828FCAD90E3F086BCB090 libspeexresampler.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3772000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 B933D3445554C18D3D0F3115FABE7F910 libunwind.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA37F1000 0000000000000000 00000000000C1000 9554AC2D0276BDCB9B4E89710972689D0 libdng_sdk.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA38BA000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 C0BCD83051D65B80FC2FC42DD7ADFF5B0 libregionalization.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA38A5000 0000000000000000 0000000000183000 9FCEFEAF5A88ADDF1E8F976D2EDB49400 libicuuc.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3A3C000 0000000000000000 000000000000A000 B1B91E5B31A2ECEDF3A4911DC039FD740 libmediautils.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3A43000 0000000000000000 00000000000BC000 A7129BA2231DF841FED49F168C2C190B0 libhwui.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3B03000 0000000000000000 00000000000FB000 0D0D64DAAC71FD11EBE6E71CF006204C0 libsqlite.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3BFE000 0000000000000000 000000000003F000 CD9C648F8BDBDAEDF3B4F2B5402CDD620 libstagefright_omx.so
07-07 05:37:54.736 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3C43000 0000000000000000 000000000002B000 E86F2FB4CBF63420A3FA14093FC774420 libstagefright_foundation.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3C71000 0000000000000000 000000000000F000 036275BBFFD044B3A89A326B07ECBEA50 liblog.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3C83000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 E788B336C9D31BC62B0DBD24E901174A0 libstagefright_http_support.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3C87000 0000000000000000 000000000000B000 32A74BDBF89F698D7D686F948166F1D40 libbase.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3C94000 0000000000000000 000000000004F000 90342BBC784292A0B28BD5461B2BE53C0 libRScpp.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3CE6000 0000000000000000 0000000000035000 132B1D48E758A3515512F3900656C8910 libm.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3D04000 0000000000000000 0000000000232000 5A218E5617E77D1B181B019A973604590 libicui18n.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3F4B000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 BE021A68F5FFFA5A1FC2AE49ADDB9BC80 libmdmdetect.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3F43000 0000000000000000 000000000002A000 ED96B2E4AB1E876E06FE4404A181C82A0 lib-imsrcscmclient.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA3F67000 0000000000000000 00000000000C7000 FFCD99C0D1DD56CC6B9B990BB58542C10 libmediaplayerservice.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA403E000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 E419FA0C7C43A6D32D8EA8F0014D71450 libsmemlog.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4041000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 A2E60C7CD3F8E08BE91340F084158F640 libqcci_legacy.so
07-07 05:37:54.737 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA404B000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 26AD0E5A1130F09B43022089487E80530 libqmi_common_so.so
07-07 05:37:54.738 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA404D000 0000000000000000 0000000000016000 87E04EE0B0561BC29EEDF6943FA72EDB0 libOpenCL.so
07-07 05:37:54.738 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4064000 0000000000000000 0000000000017000 0C1C9F5F950F85F2872F92EBDEDBD65E0 libmediandk.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA407B000 0000000000000000 0000000000016000 9362F55ECDA1222597401E735832A7800 libmediadrm.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA40C3000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 EDB71337485BFF5DB756A977DCA9D6E80 libcamera2ndk.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA410B000 0000000000000000 0000000000006000 10858F8B118C8EDB696A27F22A89DE500 libqti-gt.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4138000 0000000000000000 000000000000E000 E60022563C2C3B21E095C38F33AA19450 lib-ims-rcscmjni.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA414D000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 843C6691981F316FD488BDD0E790B2A60 libsechook.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA415C000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 DFB4FFBF8EAB597A5C0B2F17ADEC79AF0 libqti-at.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4164000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 B398B9DEBF5C63DCF723F4F8ACED0D920 memtrack.msm8996.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4168000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 C06631C0654850846F654D4CD69AF13A0 libGLESv3.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA41AE000 0000000000000000 0000000000008000 3D1528B28BBF44904AEF96CDDF95300F0 libopenjdkjvm.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA41E9000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 47A026BCF480716C7CCB1DC6A0AA89A50 libandroid.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA424E000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 9A327E191A7B55D7DE451749358886680 libqti-perfd-client.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4252000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 AA1397F65E2069CEC5DA99AA7A136F2F0 libqti_performance.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4256000 0000000000000000 0000000000003000 EB2BB67B35317F3BA5B93BF2749C75370 libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA425B000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 1A296C5D4B35AC8981F6E20379D5DE8A0 libOpenSLES.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA42F8000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 92D493C5853E0D3C4741147781C481C90 libOpenMAXAL.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA42FA000 0000000000000000 000000000002E000 332FAAE8BC4EBAE83F3E046FABFD33A70 libdashplayer.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4332000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 DDC69ACD60BB86707C7886B9FC6822DE0 libjnigraphics.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4339000 0000000000000000 000000000000C000 DD29E353E7626318AF06ADBB7658183F0 liblz4.so
07-07 05:37:54.739 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA4373000 0000000000000000 000000000002C000 E304FFB3F3BCBA2C69E381F4072B71450 libstagefright_httplive.so
07-07 05:37:54.740 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA439C000 0000000000000000 0000000000049000 6EB3706D5E26FC2B6394E1E3860319B80 libavenhancements.so
07-07 05:37:54.740 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA440E000 0000000000000000 000000000003B000 086086B0C9494AF58CE1AAA6BD9FF9B10 libstagefright_wfd.so
07-07 05:37:54.740 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA44A3000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 510A7F5CC03B36DD82E46BD44BF2BD370 libsigchain.so
07-07 05:37:54.740 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA44FC000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 B6A1B7587B9EA1A02A6C01AE893B989C0 libExtendedExtractor.so
07-07 05:37:54.741 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA453C000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 67D42CD6CF8AF63B3BD7F02AB02B3D0C0 linux-gate.so
07-07 05:37:54.741 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA453D000 0000000000000000 00000000000A9000 38925412BAA565C081366DE25E7D87A30 linker64
07-07 05:37:54.741 24137 32072 F google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
07-07 05:37:54.799 32022 32072 W google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
07-07 05:37:54.800 32022 32072 W google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
07-07 05:37:54.800 32022 32072 W google-breakpad: 1.1.8 1707042
07-07 05:37:54.800 32022 32072 W google-breakpad: 18
07-07 05:37:54.800 32022 32072 W google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
07-07 05:37:54.801 32022 32072 E CrashReport: Old handler addresss 0x7fa4543d34
07-07 05:37:54.801 32022 32072 E CrashReport: HandleSignal start 11
07-07 05:37:54.801 32022 32072 E CrashReport: NativeRQDVersion:2.1.2
07-07 05:37:54.804 32022 32072 E CrashReport: can't start default dump in 64bit!
07-07 05:37:54.874  1415  2642 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{8387c5d u0 com.miaomiaoce.mmc.owl/com.miaomiaoce.mmc.owl.OWL_Monitor_Activity}
07-07 05:37:54.874  1415  3260 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ id=54, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ], android.os.BinderProxy@5b7a2af)
07-07 05:37:54.875  1415  2642 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.miaomiaoce.mmc.owl/com.miaomiaoce.mmc.owl.OWL_Monitor_Activity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2027 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:894 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1450 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2491 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2449 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1781 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:696  
07-07 05:37:54.875  1415  3260 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) Binder:1415_10 expire 4 lines
07-07 05:37:54.875  1415 23127 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ id=53, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ], android.os.BinderProxy@51bc6bc)
07-07 05:37:54.875  1721  2014 D BtGatt.GattService: Binder is dead - unregistering client (13)!

The app keep a ble connect,and show the data on webveiw.

Phone info:xiaomi 5,android 7.0.We also get this crash on other phone.